# Drop Down List Text does not appear in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am accessing external website into windows phone app.Front end as Xaml has an

```
<phone:WebBrowser Source="http://hc.tap.nic.in/Hcdbs/searchdates.do" />
```

The drop down dates text does not appear in mobile app.

where as in desktop browser drop down dates does appear.

Comment: Just visited the site.  Drop down is empty in my desktop browser.  I'm using Firefox 45.

Comment: How about in mobile app ?